# Prevent MDC-dialog from closing

Tags: dialog, material-design, mdc

Is it possible to stop the dialog from closing when using the accept/cancel listeners? I've now set a custom button in my dialog. Is there something build-in in the MDC-dialog component to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Github issue for tracking this feature - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1323.

Comment: @BrantOlsen it is possible to prevent closing the dialog when I click outside?

Answer (score 4):

Accordingly, to the documentation, you can disable escape and click on the scrim by setting the following parameters.

```
const dialog_add_user = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector('#dialog_form_user'));
    dialog_add_user.escapeKeyAction = "";
    dialog_add_user.scrimClickAction = "";
```

Also, remove data-mdc-dialog-action="xxxxx" from your buttons to keep the dialog open.

I hope it helps.

Comment: kindly add relevant explanation to your answer